# How to measure user priority over a request in teradata?

Tags: sql, request, teradata

In Teradata, I have set two different priorities (low and high) for two different users.

Is there something that can prove that a request sent simultaneously by these two users will be treated differently according to the user priority ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you have workload management defined in your environment.

DBQL will track the initial and final workload assigned to each query in the QryLog table. Combined with the mapping of your operating environment, health condition, state, resource partitions, allocation grouping, and relative weighting at the time of execution you can prove which workload ran at a higher priority.

Comment: I didn't know QryLog table even existed. I can now compare the processing time between 2 requests. Thanks !!